# Block sparse matrices as sparse matrices

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

Given a sparse matrix `M`, which is `32x24` I'm trying to create a larger sparse matrix of this form:

`A = [[O(32),M],[t(M),O(24)]]`

Here `O(n)` is a zero sparse matrix of dimension `nxn`.

`M` itself is a block matrix:

`M = [[m.aa,m.ab],[m.ba,m.bb]]`

where `m.ij` is `16x12`.

I'm using the `Matrix` package for `sparsematrix` and `blockmatrix` for `blockmatrix`. One problem I have is that the `use.as.blockmatrix=FALSE` parameter, which works nicely for ordinary block matrices, seems not to work properly for block sparse matrices. I can't take the transpose of the block matrices in question, which makes the construction of `A` difficult.

Here's how I'm generating `m.ij`:

```
  m.aa<-rsparsematrix(
    #dimensions:
    nrow=16,ncol=12,
    nnz=20,
    rand.x=function(x) 1 )

  m.ab<-rsparsematrix(
    #dimensions:
    nrow=16,ncol=12,
    nnz=10,
    rand.x=function(x) 1 )

 m.ba<-rsparsematrix(
    nrow=16,ncol=12,
    nnz=0,
    rand.x=function(x) 1 )

  m.bb<-m.aa



M<-blockmatrix(dim=c(2,2),names=c("maa","mba","mab","mbb"),
                 maa=m.aa,mab=m.ab,mba=m.ba,mbb=m.bb,
                 use.as.blockmatrix=FALSE)
```

But `attr(M,"class")` shows `M` is still a `blockmatrix`, even though I have `use.as.blockmatrix=FALSE`.

I can create `O(32)` and `O(24)`, but `t(M)` gives me the error message `argument is not a matrix`, so I can't use it for block `A(2,1)` :(

`A` might be constructed with something like:

```
Mt<-t(M)

O32<-rsparsematrix(nrow=32,ncol=32,nnz=0)
O24<-rsparsematrix(nrow=24,ncol=24,nnz=0)

A<-blockmatrix(dim=c(2,2),names=c("RR","BR","RB","BB"), RR=O32,RB=M,BR=Mt,BB=O24)
```

Comment: what are `mij.rowCount` and `mij.colCount` ?

Comment: does `M <- cBind(rBind(m.aa,m.ba),rBind(m.ab,m.bb))` work?

Comment: @BenBolker fixed, regarding those constant names. `rbind,cbind` seems to work for `M`, but `A` will require a trick, because the dimensions don't match that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perhaps a little awkward, but rather than using `blockmatrix` you can put together the appropriate blocks yourself using `rBind()`, `cBind()`, and `Matrix(0,...)`:

```
M <- cBind(rBind(m.aa,m.ba),rBind(m.ab,m.bb))   
A <- rBind(
    cBind(Matrix(0,32,32), M              ),
    cBind(t(M),            Matrix(0,24,24))
)
```